# Nodejs project unable to start in heroku

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, heroku

I am trying to deploye nodejs application in heroku.com. i am successfully push the code in `heroku master`. When i am trying to access this application it is showing below error.

[image]

I check log also and below error i am getting.

```
2018-07-25T06:17:36.798787+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2018-07-25T06:17:39.066859+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-07-25T06:17:39.066885+00:00 app[web.1]: > nodegigapi@0.0.0 start /app
2018-07-25T06:17:39.066887+00:00 app[web.1]: > node ./bin/www
2018-07-25T06:17:39.066888+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-07-25T06:17:39.138914+00:00 app[web.1]: module.js:549
2018-07-25T06:17:39.138917+00:00 app[web.1]: throw err;
2018-07-25T06:17:39.138918+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2018-07-25T06:17:39.138920+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-07-25T06:17:39.138921+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module '/app/bin/www'
2018-07-25T06:17:39.138923+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
2018-07-25T06:17:39.138924+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
2018-07-25T06:17:39.138925+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
2018-07-25T06:17:39.138926+00:00 app[web.1]: at startup (bootstrap_node.js:191:16)
2018-07-25T06:17:39.138927+00:00 app[web.1]: at bootstrap_node.js:612:3
2018-07-25T06:17:39.144035+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2018-07-25T06:17:39.144315+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2018-07-25T06:17:39.145314+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! nodegigapi@0.0.0 start: `node ./bin/www`
2018-07-25T06:17:39.145428+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2018-07-25T06:17:39.145607+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2018-07-25T06:17:39.145751+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the nodegigapi@0.0.0 start script.
2018-07-25T06:17:39.149954+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-07-25T06:17:39.145852+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2018-07-25T06:17:39.150091+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2018-07-25T06:17:39.150165+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2018-07-25T06_17_39_147Z-debug.log
2018-07-25T06:17:39.195926+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2018-07-25T06:17:39.212995+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2018-07-25T06:17:39.215182+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2018-07-25T06:17:41.663113+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2018-07-25T06:17:43.846000+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-07-25T06:17:43.846025+00:00 app[web.1]: > node ./bin/www
2018-07-25T06:17:43.846023+00:00 app[web.1]: > nodegigapi@0.0.0 start /app
2018-07-25T06:17:43.846027+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-07-25T06:17:43.920839+00:00 app[web.1]: module.js:549
2018-07-25T06:17:43.920842+00:00 app[web.1]: throw err;
2018-07-25T06:17:43.920843+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2018-07-25T06:17:43.920847+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
2018-07-25T06:17:43.920844+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-07-25T06:17:43.920845+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module '/app/bin/www'
2018-07-25T06:17:43.920848+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
2018-07-25T06:17:43.920850+00:00 app[web.1]: at startup (bootstrap_node.js:191:16)
2018-07-25T06:17:43.920849+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
2018-07-25T06:17:43.920852+00:00 app[web.1]: at bootstrap_node.js:612:3
2018-07-25T06:17:43.926342+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2018-07-25T06:17:43.926056+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2018-07-25T06:17:43.927330+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! nodegigapi@0.0.0 start: `node ./bin/www`
2018-07-25T06:17:43.927429+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2018-07-25T06:17:43.927591+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2018-07-25T06:17:43.927697+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the nodegigapi@0.0.0 start script.
2018-07-25T06:17:43.927800+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2018-07-25T06:17:43.934451+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2018-07-25T06_17_43_929Z-debug.log
2018-07-25T06:17:43.934236+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-07-25T06:17:43.934368+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

Below is my project structure.i am starting the applicaton by `npm start` command. and `app.js` have my server code. In public folder i have angular js 1 code.

**app.js**

```
app.use('/api', googleRouter);

app.listen(2020, function () {
  console.log('Server strated on port 2020 !');
});

module.exports = app;
```

[image]

**bin/www**

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var app = require('../app');
var debug = require('debug')('nodegigapi:server');
var http = require('http');

/**
 * Get port from environment and store in Express.
 */

var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
app.set('port', port);

/**
 * Create HTTP server.
 */

var server = http.createServer(app);

/**
 * Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
 */

server.listen(port);
server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);

/**
 * Normalize a port into a number, string, or false.
 */

function normalizePort(val) {
  var port = parseInt(val, 10);

  if (isNaN(port)) {
    // named pipe
    return val;
  }

  if (port >= 0) {
    // port number
    return port;
  }

  return false;
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "error" event.
 */

function onError(error) {
  if (error.syscall !== 'listen') {
    throw error;
  }

  var bind = typeof port === 'string'
    ? 'Pipe ' + port
    : 'Port ' + port;

  // handle specific listen errors with friendly messages
  switch (error.code) {
    case 'EACCES':
      console.error(bind + ' requires elevated privileges');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    case 'EADDRINUSE':
      console.error(bind + ' is already in use');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    default:
      throw error;
  }
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "listening" event.
 */

function onListening() {
  var addr = server.address();
  var bind = typeof addr === 'string'
    ? 'pipe ' + addr
    : 'port ' + addr.port;
  debug('Listening on ' + bind);
}
```

Can anyone guide me on this ?

Comment: Is this default `express` generated boilerplate ? or you set it up manually ? and share `bin/www` source ?

Comment: default express generated @KamalakannanJ

Comment: @KamalakannanJ please check `bin/www` code

Comment: Have a look into : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35663469/how-to-write-procfile-for-node-js-heroku-deployment-using-bin-www/42683595#42683595

Comment: @Swati where i need to put this `web: ./bin/www npm start`

Comment: Are you using two node.js servers? In your app.js, you are using raw port number 2020. You should change it to (process.env.PORT || '2020')

Comment: @BMShamsNahid so port may be impact for this ?

Comment: Maybe an explicit port is causing the problem.

Comment: @BMShamsNahid, i'll try this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need create file Procfile upload to heroku, you can try the following below or you see:[How to Deploy a Node.js App to Heroku](https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-node-js-app-to-heroku)

```html
//Procfile
web: node app.js

//app.js
var express =  require('express');
var app      = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);

app.get('/',function(req,res){
 res.send('Hello');
})

http.listen(process.env.PORT || 8888, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:8888');
});
```

Comment: `Procfile` should be inside root project folder ? and need to push again to heroku master ?